# Tracking Master node failure in Multi-master AWS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Am using EMR 5.26 cluster version in AWS and it supports having multiple Master nodes(3 Master nodes). This is to remove the single point failure of the cluster. When a master node gets terminated, another node takes it's place as master node and keeps the EMR Cluster and it's steps running.

Here the issue is, am trying to track the exact time when a master node goes into problem(termination). And also the time taken by another node to take it's place and become the new Master node.

Couldn't find any detailed documentation on tracking the failure of master node in AWS Multi master cluster and hence posting it here.

Comment: even if hte node goes down the EMR restarts the node. A node may not be master, for several reasons --node crashing being just one. Why do u wnat to know the exact time? Btw, u can use EMR apis to know the current master node. Keep in mind that EMR apis have rate limits

Comment: We are trying to track the potential delay that we might encounter for the other services deployed in the EMR. For that we are trying to identify the exact time between one master node going down and another master taking up the processes. Also, we are trying to track the failover process through logs even, if that's possible. But no luck finding data for that so far.

Comment: but shouldnt the retry mechanism on the caller handle all these issues?

Comment: Yes, it should. But we would like to be notified whenever this happens. We tried to implement this based on the logs or any api notification we could get. So far we couldn't get a way to implement the same. Failed master node and bringing up new one are all handled internally by AWS and we don't have any visibility. EMR multi master node is still being stabilized and there are still issues(like status of 'step' in EMR) being addressed in updates from AWS.